# Cross-browser method for hiding page elements until all content is loaded to prevent layout from appearing broken during load?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css3pie

I have an issue where due to some elements loading faster than others, the page looks broken for a few seconds at the start. An example is the CSS Pie behavior that allows me to do curved corners in IE, it appears before it becomes curved which looks bad. What would be ideal would be it somehow knowing when everything is loaded and then appear all at once, possibly including some kind of elegant visual way of not making the user feel impatient... any ideas or common tricks for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a css class to the `<body>` tag by default and use some javascript to remove that css class once the page is loaded?

```
<body class="notready" onload="this.className = '';">
</body>
```

with some css classes defined to hide the things you do not want to show just yet:

```
body.notready .myclassname { display: none; }
```